# ASP.net/C# SqlDataReader and Decimal problem

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to use SqlDataReader to read a Decimal(10,2) from a MSSQL database into a formatted string like 8.80.

```
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
xxx =  reader["xxx"] //???
```

I tried several ways but always got 8.00 instead of 8.80. And I can confirm the data in database is 8.80.

Could anyone tell me how to do this? Thanks.

Edit:
Thanks for your time. It turns out that I mistype in my code. Every way I tried actually works well....

Comment: What is the data type of xxx?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

reader["xxx"] is returning an object. If you are sure this column is a decimal then cast it to decimal `decimal xxx = (Decimal)reader["xxx"];`

Comment: Oh. I mistyped in my code.......... Every way I tried works now... Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Use [SQLDataReader.GetDecimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getdecimal.aspx) method.